# Ubuntu 23.10 not mounting the expansion drive

Tags: mount, drive

These shots are when I opened the logs:

[image][image][image][image]

The rest should be self-explanatory as they are the log entries with time stamps.
enter image description here

> 

I hope they all were posted there.

Once again, I am seeking access to my 1Tb expansion drive.I don't know where to start.

I did notice the error message stating /dev/sda1 when the drive is /dev/sdf1, the screenshot did not catch the notice.